# Unable to install phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I'm following this link: [click here!](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04)
I ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then I restarted apache2 by using this command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then I went to http://localhost/phpmyadmin in browser and I got this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
```

Where did things go wrong?
P.S: This is the 3rd time that I'm trying to install `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Sounds like it didn't add your conf correctly, so you might need to do it manually. There are also other ways of installing it, it's just a PHP app after all.  Read through this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: http://tecadmin.net/install-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu/

You have to edit your conf file

Answer (score 1):

You must have a LAMP server in order to work with phpmyadmin.

In your case, I think you haven't installed MySQL.

You can install the entire LAMP by the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

It’s important to remember the caret (^) at the end of the command.

During the installation, MySQL will ask you to set a root password.

Step by step installation of LAMP server is described in this [link](https://junise.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/how-to-install-lamp-server-in-ubuntu/).

As you have already installed phpmyadmin, you now need to configure apache.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
# phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Restart apache with the following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now phpmysql will be working in http://localhost/phpmyadmin/.